# Guide for users who've never heard of linux ( and are 8 years old )?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

My wife's cousins had a useless computer because their mother loaded it with so many viruses it couldn't run. I got tired of cleaning it up and just put lubuntu 14.04 on it. I installed libre office and put nice big shortcuts on the desktop so hopefully they can do homework and use the internet. I cannot stay to answer all the questions they may have, and I would like to leave some resource they can use to learn how to use it better. They are not computer literate, and the smartest one is only 8, but I want to at least give them a chance.

Is there a decent reference for ABSOLUTE beginners to get introduced to linux, specifically lubuntu?

Maybe I should just figure out how to remote desktop my way in...

Comment: have a look here: http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/linux-for-children.html

Comment: As this is not a very explicit support question it may be deleted, the Ubuntu manual should be enought for the basic stuff https://ubuntu-manual.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my own experience with my kids operating Ubuntu since they are 6 years old.

- Children are born computer illiterate. It does not matter to them what OS they are on, all and everything is new.
- Guides are written by and for adults. They won't understand them. Whenever they look up things (e.g. how to install Minecraft mods) they exclusively use video tutorials.
- Kids love to experiment. We need to makes sure that we can reset the system any time. Automated backups in the background are a good means for quick repair if all went wrong.
- We should only grant them sudo permissions if we were happy with frequent reinstallations.
- They get on very well with the desktop, and how to use their applications. They learn by doing, trying, clicking here, clicking there. At the end of the day they manage to do whatever they need without any guide.
- In case they get stuck, it may be a good idea to have access to that machine (e.g. physically or remotely with VNC or SSH). This helps to reduce frustration.
- Don't over-protect them. A locked down restricted machine is bad for experimenting. In the long run it is better to not leave them alone.
- Install an Internet site rating tool for the browser and educate them why there are warnings for some sites.
- Complaints about their friend's Windows to be so much better will come. Discuss advantages and disadvantages of **both** systems to let them decide on their own (yes, they can do that).

Comment: the point about frequent installs is important. I left them the the live CD, and that's all I can do. They lost the password for their router so I can't do port forwarding for SSH yet. Might consider having them do a factory reset so they can get back in. I'm mostly hoping they don't poke around too much to break anything.

Comment: **WARNING:** WOT-ratings may be (partly) ok, but do **NOT install any WOT-software**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: at the time I wrote the answer WOT leaks were not yet an issue. Thanks for pointing to this. I removed the reference. Any rating tool we trust serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For Lubuntu/Ubuntu, Here is some helpful links:

- [Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation)& [FAQ/Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/FAQ/Guides)
- [Thread from ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1880394)
- **Recommended** [**Ubuntu Guide**](http://ubuntuguide.org/)
- [Tips & Tutorial](http://ubuntuguide.net/)

For question/query [**on-topic**](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), ask on [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).